# Recursive function vs recursive variable in F#

Tags: recursion, f#

The first method is OK.
The second repeats constantly the same pair of numbers.

It is quite obscure to me why... Could you point to the good direction ?

```
module Normal = 
   let rnd = new MersenneTwister()
   let sampleNormal = 
      fun () -> let rec randomNormal() = let u1, u2 = rnd.NextDouble(),rnd.NextDouble()
                                         let r, theta= sqrt (-2. * (log u1)), 2. * System.Math.PI * u2  
                                         seq { yield r * sin theta; yield r * cos theta ; printfn "next";yield! randomNormal() }
                randomNormal()

   let sampleNormalBAD = 
      fun () -> let rec randomNormal = let u1, u2 = rnd.NextDouble(),rnd.NextDouble()
                                       let r, theta= sqrt (-2. * (log u1)), 2. * System.Math.PI * u2  
                                       seq { yield r * sin theta; yield r * cos theta ; printfn "next";yield! randomNormal }
                randomNormal

Normal.sampleNormal() |> Seq.take(10) |>Seq.toArray
Normal.sampleNormalBAD() |> Seq.take(10) |>Seq.toArray
```

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with immutability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first sample `randomNormal()` is a function, it takes `()` and return a value, it will be evaluated each time.
In the second one `randomNormal` is a value, so it will not be evaluated twice, once bounded it will remain with the same value.

If you rollover `randomNormal()` the signature is :

```
unit->seq<float>
```

and for `randomNormal` is just :

```
seq<float>
```

UPDATE: It keeps printing because the `printfn` is inside the sequence, which is the bounded value.
If you try printing in the body before the last line you will see the difference. Here's a simplified sample code:

```
let sampleNormal = 
    fun () -> 
        let rec randomNormal() = 
            let u1, u2 = 1,2
            printfn "Evaluating"
            seq { yield u1; yield u2 ; printfn "next";yield! randomNormal() }
        randomNormal()

let sampleNormalBAD = 
    fun () -> 
        let rec randomNormal = 
            let u1, u2 = 1,2 
            printfn "Evaluating"
            seq { yield u1; yield u2 ; printfn "next";yield! randomNormal }
        randomNormal
```

Comment: It makes sense, but somehow "running" prints on both, so I'd have expected that rnd.NextDouble() would have been reevaluated as well.  May be that #nowarn 40 is meaningful in the end (sic).

Comment: So the key lies in the notion of binding you are saying

Comment: Yes, that's why it will remain always with the same value.

Comment: It's true, it keeps printing. It seems it capture both the value and the side effect. Very interesting +1.

Comment: I'll re-read carefully the binding mecanism, to pinpoint what it does precisely.

Comment: If you calculate the random inside the Seq expression it will work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13319/discussion-between-gustavo-and-nicolas)

Answer (score 0):

Completing Gustavo's answer, `randomNormal` is a value and after being computed by the interpreter, is bound to a sequence.

Further calls to `randomNormal` will yield this sequence, and the bindings used before the sequence have no reason to be evaluated. t, theta etc.. will always have the same value.
What is ***inside*** the sequence will be evaluated though, hence the print.

In the case of  `randomNormal()` the same happens, but the bindings are evaluated, as function might be relying on side effects.