# Recursive object warning using a seq expression

Tags: f#

I've got the following (simplified) code:

```
open System
open System.IO

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =     
    let rec lineseq = seq {
        match Console.ReadLine() with
        | null -> yield! Seq.empty
        | line ->
            yield! lineseq
        }

    0
```

Visual studio is emitting an "recursive object" warning for the second yield statement, namely `yield! lineseq`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are defining `lineseq` as a value.

Just write  `#nowarn "40"`  at the beginning as the warning suggest, or add a dummy parameter so it becomes a function:

```
open System
open System.IO

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =     
    let rec lineseq x = seq {
        match Console.ReadLine() with
        | null -> yield! Seq.empty
        | line ->
            yield! lineseq x
        }

    // But then you need to call the function with a dummy argument.
    lineseq () |> ignore

    0
```

Also note that the sequence will still not be evaluated, and ReadLine will return no `null`, I guess you are waiting for an empty line which is `""`.

Try something like this in order to visualize the results:

```
let main argv =     
    let rec lineseq x = seq {
        match Console.ReadLine() with
        | ""   -> yield! Seq.empty
        | line -> yield! lineseq x}

    lineseq () |> Seq.toList |> ignore
    0
```

It has a ressemblance to this question: [Recursive function vs recursive variable in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285286/recursive-function-vs-recursive-variable-in-f/11285409#11285409)

Comment: Ahh, whoops. I guess it's because it's eagerly evaluated perhaps?

Comment: Yes, values might be evaluted eagerly, this is not the case because it is a seq which is lazy.